# [ADB AUTO DEBUGGING]How to make a Samsung S9 Plus (star2qltechn) phone automatically recognize ADB debug [lineageOS 18.1]

Tags: adb

I have extracted the Lineage OS 18.1 ROM and added the following lines to the file: "build.prop" in folder "system"

```
ro.debuggable=1
ro.adb.secure=0
ro.force.debuggable=1
ro.secure=0
persist.adb.notify=0
persist.sys.auto_confirm=1
persist.service.adb.enable=1
persist.service.debuggable=1
persist.sys.usb.config=mtp,adb
```

The installation process is complete, but there is still a confirmation prompt for the connection. Previously, when I added those lines, the phone automatically enabled the ADB function without any notification.I hope to receive your assistance!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOvzc.jpg)